# using aliased with Moose doesn't seem to work when declaring classes

Tags: perl, perl-module, moose

I'm a bit new to Perl. I'm trying to define/use a class in the following manner:

```
package A::B::C;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;
use aliased 'A::B::D';
has 'attribute' => (isa => 'ArrayRef[D]', is => 'ro', required => 1);
```

While creating an object:

```
use aliased 'A::B::C';
use aliased 'A::B::D';
my $aref = [D->new()];
C->new($aref);
```

However this fails as Moose complains:

```
Attribute (attribute) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'ArrayRef[D]' with value ARRAY(0x7f2b658b51c0)
```

But, if I switch to not using aliases, it works(as it of course should):

```
package A::B::C;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;
use A::B::D;
has 'attribute' => (isa => 'ArrayRef[A::B::D]', is => 'ro', required => 1);
```

My question is why does the use aliased bit not work with Moose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Moose doesn't know about `use aliased`.  The pragma `use aliased` is a hack on top of Perl; all it does is create a subroutine with a short name that returns the class name.  So

```
use aliased 'A::B::D';
```

is equivalent to

```
use A::B::D;

sub D() { 'A::B::D' }
```

(see [aliased.pm#L45](https://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/aliased-0.34/lib/aliased.pm#L45))

Then, when you say something like `D->new()`, Perl notices that there is a subroutine (constant) named `D` and interprets `D` as a subroutine call, then does the method call on the result.  (Rather than interpreting `D` as a string constant like it normally would).  Even to Perl, `D` is not really a package name; just something that acts like a package name!

Furthermore, Moose has its own system for parsing type declarations (which is why you can give them as a string like you did) and its own global notion of type declarations.  None of that knows about `aliased`, so Moose is using its default behavior of treating un-recognized types as (global) package names.

If you understand how `aliased` works, you could take advantage of it by doing

```
has 'attribute' => (isa => 'ArrayRef['.D.']', is => 'ro', required => 1);
```

but it's probably better to remember that

> [Type names are global throughout the current Perl interpreter](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod#TYPE-NAMES)

and either use fully-qualified package names as types everywhere, or use [Type::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Type-Tiny/lib/Type/Tiny/Manual.pod) and write

```
package A::B::C;

use Moose;

use aliased 'A::B::D';

use Types::Standard qw/ ArrayRef /;
use Type::Utils qw( class_type );

has 'attribute' => (isa => ArrayRef[class_type D], is => 'ro', required => 1);
```

(note the lack of quotes around `D`, possible only because of the `use aliased`!).

(`Type::Tiny` will probably be faster than Moose types, so you might want to consider it anyway).

Comment: is that the standard/recommended way to use short names for imports? what I want to make sure is that the approach I end up using doesn't have any such gotchas associated with it and just works when used as a replacement to specifying the entire path.